# NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: The constructor for contracts/FundMe.sol:FundMe has 1 parameters but 0 arguments were provided instead at encodeArgument

Tags: node.js, solidity, yarnpkg, hardhat

This is the error I'm getting.

I tried It without verifying on etherscan it still gave the same error I am deploying it on the goerli network Pls have a look at that pls

```
yarn run v1.22.15
warning ..\package.json: No license field
$ "E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\.bin\hardhat" deploy --tags all --network goerli
Nothing to compile
5
ethUsdPriceFeedAddress 0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e
reusing "FundMe" at 0x6DD6B9f3bD775549Ef0e6423C49c9d03AC6bb778
Verifying Contracts.........
Nothing to compile
NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: The constructor for contracts/FundMe.sol:FundMe has 1 parameters
but 0 arguments were provided instead.
    at encodeArguments (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-etherscan\src\ABIEncoder.ts:29:13)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.verifySubtask [as action] (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-etherscan\src\index.ts:283:34)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
    at Environment.run (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:131:14)
    at verify (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\utils\verify.js:6:9)
    at Object.module.exports [as func] (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\deploy\01_fudme_deploy.js:31:9)
    at DeploymentsManager.executeDeployScripts (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1219:22)
    at DeploymentsManager.runDeploy (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:1052:5)
    at SimpleTaskDefinition.action (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\index.ts:438:5)
    at Environment._runTaskDefinition (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:219:14)

    Caused by: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":1,"values":0}, value={"types":[{"name":"priceFeed","type":"address","indexed":null,"components":null,"arrayLength":null,"arrayChildren":null,"baseType":"address","_isParamType":true}],"values":[]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)        at Logger.makeError (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
        at Logger.throwError (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
        at AbiCoder.encode (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\abi-coder.ts:101:20)
        at Interface._encodeParams (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\interface.ts:323:31)
        at Interface.encodeDeploy (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\interface.ts:327:21)
        at encodeArguments (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-etherscan\src\ABIEncoder.ts:22:8)
        at SimpleTaskDefinition.verifySubtask [as action] (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-etherscan\src\index.ts:283:34)
        at Environment._runTaskDefinition (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:219:14)
        at Environment.run (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\runtime-environment.ts:131:14)
        at verify (E:\Block Chain Projects\FUND_ME_FULLSTACK\utils\verify.js:6:9)
```

**MY 00_fundme_deploy.js**
I am trying to deploy a crowd funding project  Its got deployed correctly on hardhat localhost network but it throws error on goerli network

```
const {networkconfig,developmentChains} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
const {getNamedAccounts,deployments,network} = require("hardhat");
const {verify} = require("../utils/verify.js");
require("dotenv").config();
    module.exports = async ({getNamedAccounts,deployments}) =>{
    const {deploy,log} = deployments;
    const {deployer}= await  getNamedAccounts();
    const chainID = network.config.chainId;
    console.log(chainID)

    //IF chain ID is A then use address B
    // IF CHAINID IS Z THEN USE C
    let ethUsdPriceFeedAddress
    if (chainID == 31337) {
        const ethUsdAggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = ethUsdAggregator.address
    } else {
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkconfig[chainID]["ethUsdPriceFeed"]
    }
    // if the Price feed contract doesnt't exists then we deploy a 
    //minimal version of our testing
    console.log("ethUsdPriceFeedAddress",ethUsdPriceFeedAddress)
    // deploy on the another network 
    const fundme = await deploy("FundMe",{
        from:deployer,
        args: [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress],
        log:true,
        waitconfirmations:network.config.blockConfirmations  || 1,
    })
    if(!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY){
        await verify(fundme.address, [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress])
    }
    log("------------------------------------------");
}
module.exports.tags = ["fund","all"];
```

**Constructor Function of FundMe.sol**

```
constructor(address priceFeed) {
        s_priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeed);
        i_owner = msg.sender;
    }
```

It takes one arguments (Pricefeed)

Comment: for some reason `args: [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress]` , `ethUsdPriceFeedAddress` is undefied here.  did this log `console.log("ethUsdPriceFeedAddress",ethUsdPriceFeedAddress)`

Comment: I'd speculate that when it's non-local hardhat env e.g. chainId !== 31337 it assigns value in else and networkconfig is misspelled should be networkConfig. OR chainID returned by network.config.chainId is string and in your config it's of type number or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue isn't with the deployment, but its with the verification, correct? If so, I think this may help as I've just encountered the same error ...

Check your `verify.js` script. This is what mine looked like when I had the error (`verify.ts`):

```
import { run } from "hardhat"

async function verify(address: string, args: any) {
  console.log("Verifying contract...")
  try {
    await run("verify:verify", {
      address: address,
      constructorArgs: args <-- THIS WAS THE ISSUE -->
    })
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
      console.log("Already verified")
    } else {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
}

export default verify
```

And I changed it to this:

```
import { run } from "hardhat"

async function verify(address: string, args: any) {
  console.log("Verifying contract...")
  try {
    await run("verify:verify", {
      address: address,
      constructorArguments: args <-- THIS WAS THE ISSUE -->
    })
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
      console.log("Already verified")
    } else {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
}

export default verify
```

I believe it was an autocomplete error!

Comment: Changing "constructorArgs" to "constructorArguments" is what solved it for me too!

Answer (score 0):

use this instead for javascript users if you can convert to typescript

```
const { run } = require("hardhat")

const verify = async function verify(contractAdress, args) {
    console.log("verifying contract !!!!!!!")

    try {
        await run("verify:verify", {
            address: contractAdress,
            constructorArguments: args,
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
            console.log("already verified")
        } else {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    verify,
}
```

I had that same issue now I had to equate the function to the variable verify, then export it from the module.exports

Answer (score 0):

```bash
yarn hardhat verify --network goerli 0x6DD6B9f3bD775549Ef0e6423C49c9d03AC6bb778 0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e
```

Try this if this work for you?

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.